# How to disable the sticky collapsible header on Blogger?

Tags: css, header, blogger, sticky

I've tried to disable the sticky collapsible header on blogger using this:

```css
.centered-top-container.sticky{
left:0;
position:fixed;
right:0;
top:0;
width:auto;
z-index:8;
```

I've changed fixed to relative and it disappeared from the homepage but it shows fixed in the middle of the posts! please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **sticky** header in Blogger, then just follow these steps:

1. Go to **Blogger > Theme > Edit HTML**
2. *Search for:* **.sticky .centered-top** CSS code
3. add **display:none;** in it.

That's it, Enjoy blogging.